# AttributeError: GraphKey

Tags: python, anaconda, faster-rcnn

This is the traceback:

```
 File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\slim\nets\inception_resnet_v2.py", line 373, in <module>
    batch_norm_updates_collections=tf.compat.v1.GraphKey.UPDATE_OPS,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v1.compat.v1' has no attribute 'GraphKey'
```

Here is the code:

```
def inception_resnet_v2_arg_scope(
    weight_decay=0.00004,
    batch_norm_decay=0.9997,
    batch_norm_epsilon=0.001,
    activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
    batch_norm_updates_collections=tf.compat.v1.GraphKey.UPDATE_OPS,
    batch_norm_scale=False):
```

I've tried using tf version 1 and 2.

Comment: What is `tf`? Do you have `import ... as tf` or something?

Comment: yes 
```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: `GraphKeys`? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/GraphKeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using Tensorflow, you want `tf.compat.v1.GraphKeys`, not `GraphKey`